# MYSQL can't add index to table

Tags: mysql, indexing, alter-table

Currently, I have '246312' records. I am trying to add index to datetime field in my table, using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE `dateup`.`Message` 
ADD INDEX `date_index` (`postedAt` DESC);
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `dateup`.`Message` 
ADD INDEX `date_index` (`postedAt` DESC)

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 2006: MySQL server has gone away
```

I have tried to set:

```
SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=1999300;
SET @@GLOBAL.max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

but still I get this error.

Comment: Did you execute repair table `dateup`.`Message` before add index?

Comment: no, i don't know what repair table is.

Comment: Execute: 
REPAIR TABLE `dateup`.`Message`; -- backup before exetute this

Comment: this is what i am getting "The storage engine for the table doesn''t support repair"

Comment: if you create table like `dateup`.`Message` with different name but with new index and dump all data to new table: insert into new_table select * from `dateup`.`Message`;
_

Answer (score 0):

i cant rebuild the database using InnoDB,
but dumping the table and import again solved this problem 
thank you